# T-SQL query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a query where this should meet the condition shown in the first screenshot. Currently, I am getting second screenshot data which is not correct.  I am having a hard time achieving this.

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(p.[prefNameFamilyName], ' ', p.[prefNameGivenName], ' ', p.[prefNameMiddleNames], ' ', pre.code, ' ', nt.code) AS PatientName,
    CONCAT(pn.familyName, ' ', pn.givenName, ' ', pn.middleNames, ' ', nt.code) AS PatientAlias,
    CONCAT(pa.streetAddressLine1, ' ', pc.code, ' ', sp.code, ' ', ap.code, ' ', ac.code, ' ', atp.code) AS PatientAddress
FROM     
    identifier.identifier I
INNER JOIN
    [Patient].[Patient] p ON i.id = p.patientIdentifierId  
INNER JOIN
    [Patient].PatientName pn ON pn.patientId = p.id  
INNER JOIN
    [Identifier].[LK_NamePrefix] pre ON pre.id = p.prefNamePrefixId 
INNER JOIN
    [Identifier].[LK_NameType] nt ON nt.id = pn.nameTypeId       
LEFT JOIN
    Patient.PatientAddress a ON a.patientId = p.id                
INNER JOIN
    [Patient].[PatientAddress] pa ON pa.patientId = p.id
INNER JOIN 
    [Address].[City] pc ON pa.cityId = pc.id
LEFT JOIN 
    [Address].[Country] ac ON ac.id = pa.countryId
LEFT JOIN
    [Address].[StateOrProvince] sp ON sp.id = pa.stateOrProvinceId
LEFT JOIN 
    [Address].[Postcode] ap ON ap.id = pa.postcodeId
LEFT JOIN 
    [Address].[AddressType] atp ON atp.id = pa.addressTypeId                  
WHERE  
    I.identifier = 'ABC123'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain "_meet the condition shown in the screenshot_" in words please? Also, some sample data and the _expected_ output could really help demonstrate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Sander, If you see the first screenshot that is what I expect but currently I getting 2nd screenshot when I use the query. One patient has many alias and also has 2 addresses. The output should be `PatientName :BOPMARY MARY MISS L`. It has 3 different alias like `BOP ALIAS ALIAS A, BOPMCP ALIAS A, BOPMCP CONNECT A`. Also the patient has 2 different address `38ONEWAY AND POBOX654`.

Comment: And how exactly you want to see those 3 aliases and 2 addresses?

Comment: @Arvo, Please have a look into last screenshot in the question. Patient `BOPMARY MARY MISS L` has 2 addresses and 3 alias. Please guide me how can I achieve it.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use common table expressions (CTE's) to isolate the joins. This solution generates row numbers for the different combinations and joins on the row numbers later on. The final step is to filter out the rows with only `null` values. This solution works for any combination of a name, one or more aliases and one or more addresses.

**Sample data**

```
declare @names table
(
    id int,
    name nvarchar(20)
);
insert into @names (id, name) values
(1, 'Bruce Wayne'),
(2, 'Peter Parker'),
(3, 'Clark Kent');

declare @aliases table
(
    id int,
    alias nvarchar(20)
)
insert into @aliases (id, alias) values
(1, 'Batman'),
(1, 'The bat'),
(1, 'Batty'),
(2, 'Spider-Man'),
(2, 'Spidey'),
(3, 'Superman');

declare @addresses table
(
    id int,
    address nvarchar(20)
);
insert into @addresses (id, address) values
(1, 'Wayne Manor'),
(1, 'The Cave'),
(2, 'Aunt May''s house'),
(3, 'The Daily Planet'),
(3, 'Krypton');
```

**Solution**

```
with cte_na as
(
    select  na.id,
            na.name,
            row_number() over(partition by na.id order by na.name) as nameNum
    from @names na
    left join @aliases al
        on al.id = na.id
    left join @addresses ad
        on ad.id = na.id
),
cte_al as
(
    select  al.id,
            al.alias,
            row_number() over(partition by al.id order by al.alias) as aliasNum
    from @aliases al
),
cte_ad as
(
    select  ad.id,
            ad.address,
            row_number() over(partition by ad.id order by ad.address) as addressNum
    from @addresses ad
)
select  cna.id,
        cna.name,
        coalesce(cal.alias, '') as alias,
        coalesce(cad.address, '') as address
from cte_na cna
left join cte_al cal
    on  cal.id = cna.id
    and cal.aliasNum = cna.nameNum
left join cte_ad cad
    on  cad.id = cna.id
    and cad.addressNum = cna.nameNum
where not (cal.id is null and cad.id is null);
```

**Result**

```
id          name                 alias                address
----------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
1           Bruce Wayne          Batman               The Cave
1           Bruce Wayne          Batty                Wayne Manor
1           Bruce Wayne          The bat              
2           Peter Parker         Spider-Man           Aunt May's house
2           Peter Parker         Spidey               
3           Clark Kent           Superman             Krypton
3           Clark Kent                                The Daily Planet
```

Comment: You are inserting data and using it. But in my scenario is different. Appreciated, if you could provide solution based on my question. I am using tables.

Comment: @KeentoLearn, [1] Yes, I am using my sample data to show the possibilities of my solution, without generating/inserting data I cannot show my results (I do not have access to your data...) [2] I am using table _variables_. They can be queried very similar compared to regular tables. Replace `@names` with `[Patient].PatientName` and so on. [3] This is not a cut-and-paste solution for your question, but shows _how_ it could be done. [4] If this solution does not work for you, update your question with your version of my solution and why it is not solving your problem.